# Removing four terms from the decic using a Tschirnhausen transformation?

Tags: polynomials, radicals, transformation, experimental-mathematics

**I. Transformation**

In this [2021 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09247), one can remove **four** terms from an equation of degree $n$ using a Tschirnhausen transformation of degree $n-1$ (and with *radical* coefficients), but only if $n\geq10$. (This high bound allows enough "free" parameters.) Specifically, in the paper, given the equation with $n\geq10$,

$$x^n+c_1x^{n-1}+c_2x^{n-2}+\dots c_n=0\tag1$$

and Tschirnhausen transformation,

$$y = a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\tag2$$

yields,

$$y^n+C_1y^{n-1}+C_2y^{n-2}+\dots+C_n = 0\tag3$$

But with appropriate *radicals* $a_n$, then,

$$C_1 = C_2 = C_3 = C_4 = 0$$

Of course, to reverse the degree $n-1$ transformation for $n=10$ is no longer in radicals, unlike the Bring quintic.

---

**II. Example**

Given a sample decic missing three terms,

$$x^{10} + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = 0$$

and the deg-$9$ transformation,

$$x^9+ax^8+bx^7+cx^6+dx^5+ex^4+fx^3+gx^2+\color{red}mx+n-y=0$$

yields,

$$y^{10}+C_1y^9+C_2y^8+C_3y^7+\dots+C_{10} = 0$$

Since the original decic is missing three terms $(x^9, x^8, x^7)$, then,

\begin{align}
C_1 &= \alpha_1\\
C_2 &= \alpha_2m+\alpha_3\\ 
C_3 &= \alpha_4m^2+\alpha_5m+\alpha_6
\end{align}

with the first three $C_n$ also missing their leading terms $(m, m^2, m^3)$, respectively, and the $a_k$ are in the other unknowns.

My theory is since one has 6 equations $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = \alpha_4 = \alpha_5 = \alpha_6 = 0$ but 8 unknowns $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,n),$ then 2 unknowns may be used to reduce the quadratics $(\alpha_3, \alpha_5)$ to linear equations like $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_4)$. But this is just a theory, since my slow computer can't handle the deg-$9$ transformation. Once the system is solved, then $m$ becomes a "free" parameter to solve,

$$C_4 = \beta_1m^4+\beta_2m^3+\beta_3m^2+\beta_4m+\beta_5 = 0$$

analogous to the method used to derive the Bring-Jerrard quintic.

---

**III. Question**

1. Anybody knows how to solve $C_1 = C_2 = C_3 = C_4 = 0$ in radicals? Or if you have the newer *Mathematica*, what are the explicit expressions for $(C_1, C_2, C_3)$ using the sample decic above? ($C_4$ is not needed.)

**P.S.** In Heberle's 2021 paper, *["Removal of 5 Terms from a Degree 21 Polynomial"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.08586.pdf)*, he takes the next step of **five** terms. There are other recent papers on Tschirnhausen transformations. With computer algebra systems like *Mathematica* or *Maple*, it makes things easier.

Comment: Related question [on the sextic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730969/4781).